# What is the name of an algorithm that does not use training data?

Tags: machine-learning

In articles on how machine learning algorithms are different from "non-machine learning" algorithms I keep reading words such as "traditional" or "classical" to describe the latter. I used the word "lazy" myself one time in lack of better alternatives but that is not right either (it's more of a "special case"). "Heuristic" is also wrong. So is there a generic term for an algorithm that does not use any training data?

Comment: Traditional or classical regression uses training data to find parameters and coefficients.  What it may lack is the practice of (cross-)validation to tune models or holding test data apart to measure out-of-sample accuracy.  So is that what you mean? Or do you mean using models which use no empirical evidence at all?

Comment: Regression can be both ML - if it is used after having been fitted on some sample data (training data) or non-ML - if it is used to fit data at "decision time". So is there any generic name for all algorithms that fit into this latter category i.e. no "pre-training"? Another example of an unsatisfactory term is "heuristic" algorithm (because it is not the same as "not-using-training-data")

Comment: “Traditional” or “classical” to me would mean methods like OLS and logistic regression, using metrics like adjusted $R^2$ and testing the fit compared to a model with fewer parameters (F-test or testing deviance against $\chi^2$), rather than out-of-sample testing, perhaps emphasizing inference on the regression parameters over getting the tightest fit possible.

Comment: "Algorithm" is a very broad term and just refers to a finite set of unambiguous instructions. That could be anything incl. "how to start your washing machine". Therefore: can you be more specific what type of non-ML algorithms you're referring to? If you do not have a precise description in mind a list of examples would be useful too to understand the scope of your question.

Comment: @Johan can you edit the examples / clarification from your first comment into the question body? It will make your question clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: Threw in the part about "heuristic". But the rest of the comment just descends down the philosophical pit-hole of "how to define regression" so don't agree that it clarifies things. Maybe a better way to put the question would be: "What is the simplest synonym to a "non-machine-learning" algorithm?" @shimao gave some ok ones but they're still a bit underwhelming IMO.

Comment: An algorithm that does some fitting at decision time and does not use training data is still a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin you're totally right my comment is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen "non-learned" or "not learning-based" used at least a few times. "Hand-crafted" or "hand-engineered" or "hard-coded" are also in use. In some contexts, talking about a "naive" agent or algorithm might also make sense.

Classical is fine, but it's not always clear from the context that classical methods don't involve learning.

Answer (score -1):

I would vote for "non-ML based algorithms" to refer to the fact that they don't dynamically learn from data. Another option I had suggested was "deterministic algorithm" but it seems to be downvoted as it is usually associated with another area of research "deterministic vs randomized algorithms"

Comment: [deterministic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) and [randomized algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm) are widely used to refer to something else entirely

Comment: "Deterministic" usually means "same input data -> same model coefficients".

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with ["Rule Based"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_system) as opposed to ML-based. 
"Classical" is very problematic - the first connotation would be "classical ML", i.e. statistical learning without neural networks (e.g. linear regression or support vector machines).
"Traditional" is very contextual, and can mean anything in the right context (e.g. "traditional neural network architectures").

Comment: Rule-based approaches are a technique in AI usually being implemented as expert systems. Although the author of this question did not clearly define what he is referring to, the example of regression shows that it is not rule-based systems (since regression is not a technique applied in rule-based systems).

Comment: You're right, I haven't read all the comments. If "regression, but fitting at decision time" is an example here, then "rule based" is not a good description.